# C3 Chart max X values (categories)

Tags: javascript, html, charts, c3.js

I need to display more categories on the X axis this should be entries from 6am to 11pm, but it only displays from 6am to 10pm. Is there any way to display more that those values I have tried changing the size of the graph, but nothing. Is there any way of doing this or is limited?

```
        var chart_loaded = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart_loaded',
    data: {
        columns: [
            loaded_orders,
            loaded_pieces
        ],
        axes: {
            Orders: 'y',
            Pieces: 'y2'
        },
        type: 'bar',
        types: {
            Pieces: 'line'
        }
    },
    axis : {
    x : {
        type : 'category',
        categories: ['6am', '7am', '8am', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm', '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm', '6pm', '7pm',
              '8pm', '9pm', '10pm', '11pm', '12am'],
        fit: false
    },
    y: {
        padding: {top: 200, bottom: 0}
    },
    y2: {
        padding: {top: 200, bottom: 0},
        show: true
    }
},
regions: [
    {axis: 'y', start: 0, end: 18, class: 'regionY'}
]
});
```

This is my output:
[image]

Comment: try fit: false in x:

Comment: I have tried, but nothing :(. Thanks

Comment: can you please set up jsfiddle and give